# If $f$ is measurable and $\int f < \infty$, then $f(x) < \infty$ a.e.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am looking for a hint for what should be a simple proof, but once again I am missing the key connection. Please don't provide a complete solution, nudge me to discover what I am missing.

> If $f$ is a measurable non-negative function and $\int f < \infty$, then $\{x : f(x) = \infty \}$ is a null set.

What I am attempting:

Define a function $g(x)$ as follows:
$$g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} a, & \textrm{if} f(x) = \infty, \\ f(x), & \textrm{otherwise}.\end{array}\right.$$

Then, we have a proposition that states that for measurable $h$, $\int h = 0 \iff h = 0$ a.e.

So what I'm trying to do is set $h = f-g$ and show that $\int h = \int f-g = 0$. This would complete the proof.

If $A = \{x : f(x) = \infty\}$, then I have $\int g = \int_{A^C} g + \int_A g = \int_{A^C} f+ a\mu(A)$. I want to use this in some way to conclude that $\mu(A) = 0$ necessarily.

The only hypothesis I have to work with is $\int f < \infty$. I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Intuitively, I know exactly what the statement means. I just can't identify the machinery needed to get to the conclusion.

Comment: $\int |f|<\infty$ by definition. Now compare the $\infty\cdot m(\{f=\infty\})$ and $\int |f|$.

Comment: @Hector Where am I getting the $\infty \cdot m(\{f = \infty\})$ from? The simple function defintion?

Comment: Yes, just look at simple functions supported on $\{f=\infty\}$ and smaller than $|f|$.

Comment: Simple functions are defined herein as taking only finite values. This unfortunately will not work.

Comment: @Arkamis look at functions that take the value $N$ on $\{f = \infty\}$ where $N \in \Bbb N$ is arbitrarily large.

Comment: This fortunately works. Think it a little. You wanted a hint or the whole solution? You don't need to take any infinite simple function. But you can give them a constant value arbitrarily large on $\{f=\infty\}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That's what I'm doing with my definition of $g$, is it not? I am still stuck.

Comment: Still stuck? Well, $n\cdot m(\{f=\infty\})=\int n\chi_{\{f=\infty\}}\leq \int |f|<\infty$.

Comment: Hang on, let me thing a second. I might have it.

Comment: Ok, I got what I needed. I was being daft.

Comment: Thanks @Omnomnomnom and Hector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of my own answer:

Define
$$
g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
a, & \textrm{if}\ f(x) = \infty, \\
f(x), & \textrm{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Since $g$ is measurable. It is clear that $f \ge g$, so we have $\int f \ge \int g$. However, we may write $\int g$ as follows:
$$
\int g = \int\limits_{\{x : f(x) < \infty\}}\mkern-24mu g\mkern12mu + \mkern6mu \int\limits_{\{x : f(x) = \infty\}}\mkern-24mu g \mkern12mu = \mkern6mu \int\limits_{\{x : f(x) < \infty\}}\mkern-24mu g +\mkern12mu a\mu(\{x : f(x) = \infty\}).
$$
But since we can choose $a$ arbitrarily large and $\int f < \infty$, then it must be the case that $\mu(\{x : f(x) = \infty\}) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have answered your own question, I'll add my two cents:

Let $E$ be the measurable domain of $f$, then for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$
\{x\in E\,:\,f(x)=\infty\}\subseteq\{x\in E\,:\,f(x)\ge n\}
$$
and by monotonicity of measure we have
$$
m(\{x\in E\,:\,f(x)=\infty\})\le m(\{x\in E\,:\,f(x)\ge n\}).
$$

Then by Chebychev's inequality we know for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that
$$
m(\{x\in E\,:\,f(x)=\infty\})\le m(\{x\in E\,:\,f(x)\ge n\})\le\frac{1}{n}\int_E f.
$$

Letting $n\to\infty$ finishes the proof.